# Explain to me the purpose of code in sample of Next.js app (canary) which uses Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js

Following to [example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-redux-wrapper)

Im trying to create my own app on **Next.js** using **Redux**

But I cant understand the purpose of the following codes in **store.js** file.
First one is:   `

```
const bindMiddleware = (middleware) => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    const { composeWithDevTools } = require('redux-devtools-extension')
    return composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
  }
 return applyMiddleware(...middleware)
}
```

And the second one is:

```
 const reducer = (state, action) => {
    if (action.type === HYDRATE) {
        const nextState = {
          ...state, // use previous state
          ...action.payload, // apply delta from hydration
        }
        if (state.count) nextState.count = state.count // preserve count value on client side navigation
        return nextState}
     else {
        return combinedReducer(state, action)
      }

}
```

Why in **first case** we should bindMiddleware if we can just make `applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)`?
in **second case** as I understand `if(state.count)` is refering to `import count from './count/reducer'`

So my question is , should I make the same if f.e I have reducer which has user information `if(state.userReducer)` and `import userReducerfrom './user/userReducer'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the first question, you may notice the syntax around checking if it is `'production'` mode. If it is production mode, work as normal, but if it isn't production mode, they are including devtools. They've written this bind function to work differently in those two different cases rather than having to do it manually.

For the second question, they are doing (state.count) to code defensively. If they try change a part of the state and it doesn't actually exist, it will run into some trouble. So instead, lets check it is actually there before editing it.